# Open specific div with specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring-mvc

I have formatted my website where links open of different divs instead of different pages.

Something like:

```
<li><a id="search-reg-options" data-display="#search-adds"
                    class="side-a-li">SEX OFFENDER SEARCH</a>
                    <div id="search-adds" class="sub-options">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a data-display="#mapdiv" class="side-a-option">SEARCH
                                    SEX OFFENDER REGISTRIES</a></li>
                            <li><a class="side-a-option">SEX OFFENDER MANAGEMENT
                                    PROGRAM SUCCESS</a></li>
                            <li><a class="side-a-option">SEX OFFENDER MANAGEMENT
                                    PROGRAM SUCCESS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div></li>

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('a').not($('#search-reg-options')).click(function(e) {
            $('.ui-show').removeClass('ui-show')
            var mydiv = $(this).data('display');
            $(mydiv).addClass('ui-show');
        });

        $('#search-reg-options').click(function(e) {
            $('.options-shown').removeClass('options-shown')
            var mydiv = $(this).data('display');
            $(mydiv).addClass('options-shown');
        });
    });
```

So that clicking on a link will open a div my changing the display. The issue with this is that I don't know how to link a user to a particular div so that when they click on the link the div is already shown.

Perhaps some javascript or something can fix this? I rather not rebuild my project so that each page is a different jsp file.

To clarify,

I want localhost:8080/frontpage/#div1 to open div1 when site loads...

This webapp has a spring MVC backbone so if that can somehow also fix it. That would also be fine.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a router. http://resthub.org/springmvc-router/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use access location.hash if it exists then run the code the same as if it were someone clicking on the anchors.

The hash property sets or returns the anchor part of a URL, including the hash sign (#).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (location.hash.length != 0) {
        $('.ui-show').removeClass('ui-show')
        var mydiv = location.hash;
        $(mydiv).addClass('ui-show');
    }

});
```

Comment: Removed reference. Added relevant piece.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  
   var tooglediv=$(this).attr('data-toggle');
   
  $(tooglediv).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
 });
```

```css
          .toggle {
                width:50px;
       height:0;
       display:none;
                background:#333;
      }
      .toggle.active {
          height:50px;
          display:block;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#toggle">click</a>
    <div class="toggle" id="toggle"></div>
```